# JPA @OneToMany with 1 - 1..* relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, one-to-many

How to properly map `@OneToMany` relationship where to create entity, on `@One` side  of `@OneToMany` relationship, it is required to have atleast one entity from `@Many` side but entity on `@Many` side also requires entity on `@One` side to exist? To put this nightmare of a sentence simply, this is the scenario I have:

This is what I want:

## `[ENTITY A] 1 <-----> (1..*)[ENTITY B]`

At the moment I have this:

## `[ENTITY A] 1 <-----> (0..*)[ENTITY B]`

Which is easily done like this.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="customer")
public Set<Agreement> agreements = new HashSet<>();
```

and

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable=false)
private Customer customer;
```

So the problem is my `CUSTOMER` table has no column corresponding to `AGREEMENT` table therefore I can't enforce rule of creating `Customer` only when `Agreement` is given. At the moment I can only setup rule to create `Agreement` when `Customer` is given because `AGREEMENT` table has column corresponding to `CUSTOMER` tabel, which is easily done by `nullable=false` condition.

Comment: I might misunderstand something here but there is no way to map a relationship without a foreign key. How is it that your Join Column is the primary key of the Customer ? It does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA doesn't provide a way to validate this, but Hibernate Validator does:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=1)
public Set<Agreement> agreements = new HashSet<>();
```

Then you have to manually test it via the Validator:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
validator.validate(customer)
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice way of preventing this programmatically, which works when I want to add something to data base through service which is provided by my app but unfortunately I can still create Customer via SQL in h2 console. I am trying to find solution to make my DB validate insertion of Customer.

Comment: Validate in H2 or in pure SQL is not that easy, I believe it could a little bit "hacky" so not so clean.

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on what type of relationship you want to enforce. If the Agreement can exist independently from the Customer then this mean that the customer_id in agreement must be nullable.

If the Agreement can not exist independently this presumes that the customer id is not nullable in which case the Agreement can not be created in first place without the customer being created.  This mean you have stronger association in between the customer and the corresponding Agreement.

Once we define that we have a relationship that is strong we need to investigate how strong it really is and who will own whom. Normaly the it is the Many side that owns the relationship and the updates are happening through the many side. This mean that your JoinColumn needs to be on the MANY and the mapped by needs to be on the ONE side.

It is interesting case when the ownership is inverse when the ONE side actually owns the relationship in this case the foreign key on the many side can not be NULL because there is no way for the owning ONE side to know what the MANY side key is.

Comment: I want to create relationship where Customer cannot exist without Agreement and Agreement cannot exist without Customer. At the moment Agreement cannot exist without Customer because of required foreign key but Customer can be created without Agreement because of lack of any foreign key in   Customer. The solution I was thinking about, I don't know if it is correct or possible, is having @OneToMany relationhip where Customer's primary key is composite key of CUSTOMER_ID and foreign key from Agreement and Agreement's primary key is just AGREEMENT_ID and Agreement requires not null foreign key.

Comment: @askstackoverflow You can not achieve this in  a non programmatic way. There is only one side that owns the relationship and controls the updates to the other side. The only to achieve this is either programmaticaly on the hibernate side as the other answer showed you . , or by implementing something on the database side that is triggered before transaction completion.

Comment: Ok thanks, then I am going to stick with programmatic way.

Comment: @askstackoverflow . I don't think that the NotNull is the way either. If you can not have a customer without agreement what you need to do is to not be able to insert Agreemnt in first place and you should have your owning side of the relationship to be the Customer. The correct thing to do is to have unidirectional one to many from Customer to Agreement and this way you create a strong association. It will create some extra update SQLs due to the nature of the unidirectional association , but than there will be no question on how strong the association is.